# maven to gradle conversion

Tags: maven, gradle, build

I am trying to convert a maven project to gradle and is looking for a corresponding tags in gradle.

Here is the POM Snippet:

```
<configuration>
                    <configurationLocations>
                        <configurationDirectory>
                            <path>src/main/environment</path>
                        </configurationDirectory>
                        <configurationArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.test.aaa</groupId>
                            <artifactId>test1.jar</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </configurationArtifact>
                        <configurationArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.test.bbb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lib1.jar</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </configurationArtifact>
                    </configurationLocations>
                    <eclipseBuildEnvironment>local</eclipseBuildEnvironment>
                    <testEnvironment>local</testEnvironment>
                </configuration>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.test.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-environments</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-environments</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-environments</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package-environments</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configurationLocations>
                        <configurationDirectory>
                            <path>src/main/environment</path>
                        </configurationDirectory>
                        <configurationArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.test.aaa</groupId>
                            <artifactId>test1.jar</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </configurationArtifact>
                        <configurationArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.test.bbb</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lib1.jar</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0</version>
                        </configurationArtifact>
                    </configurationLocations>
                    <eclipseBuildEnvironment>local</eclipseBuildEnvironment>
                    <testEnvironment>local</testEnvironment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The corresponding gradle configuration i added is as below

```
apply plugin: myapp-generator

buildscript {
    repositories {}
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.test.myapp:my-plugin:1.0.0' 
   }
```

So what I am looking up ithe corresponding script in gradle for 
 the node `<configuration>` in the POM

Comment: Your POM contains a custom Maven plugin `my-plugin`. Adding it as dependency in Gradle will not run it. You need to find a way to run a Maven plugin in Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Maven plugins cannot be used by Gradle. Given that the POM extract is mostly about a custom plugin and its configuration, you will have to develop a matching [Gradle plugin](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/) to replicate the features of the Maven plugin.